# InputStream read to byte array - will it mix messages

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, byte, server

Let's say I have a connected socket and I'm listening, reading bytes to a buffer of 1024 size for example. If there were 2 messages sent, one after another, will this read method read for example the whole first message and then a bit of the next one, or somehow separate between the messages?

Comment: I'd say you need a `Map<Socket, byte[]>` here where each key-value pair holds a buffer, associated to the client connection. Better than that would be a buffer distribution for each connection, so that you don't need to have separate buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InputStream doesn't have any idea where the first message ends and the second message starts. So it could read 2 bytes, then 1024 bytes, then 32 bytes, although the messages are 512 bytes and 546 bytes respectively.

You thus need to define a clear protocol, based on separators or on fixed message lengths, or on packets composed, for example, on a message length + the message body.

Comment: Ok, that's what I suspected. I am writing a WebSocket server so the protocol is already there that I have to use, it actually works for single byte reading, but I want to make it more efficient. I'll have to read and decode message length and then read the rest to an array at once.